# connect to mobile broadband using dongle

Tags: wireless, 12.10, vpn, mobile-broadband

so i bought this vodafone dongle K4201 I. however whenever i connect it to my laptop on ubuntu 12.10 it doesn't show any internet to connect to. i tried using the option 'create vpn connection' but the first window where its supposed to recognise the device is greyed out. i guess the drivers aren't installed on ubuntu for the dongle. so i copied the installation files given on the dongle and uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-LesTcmHNFyVTZ3ZXZfMVhhNTA&usp=sharing 
can anyone tell me how to install it properly on ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn) is something completely different. You want to create a new mobile broadband connection. Generally you do not need to install a driver, it's mostly USB modeswitch which causes trouble. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MobileWirelessBroadband

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command `$sudo -u root ./install.sh` from folder where install.sh is stored in terminal. It installs successfully with root privileges.

Comment: thanx man worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Please check your dongle's folder. It might have a Linux installation folder in it. Follow the instructions and install it. Hope it helps!

Comment: yup that's the folder i uploaded on google drive. i hv provided the link in the question

Comment: Yes I am facing the same problems with my dongle. The files in the folder do not seem to work. I found thishttp://krblogs.com/post/62519969772/airtel-4g-lte-on-linux. See if u find something similar for your make.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problems. Is your donglr ZTE or Huawei? Because ZTE dongles have a reputation of not working on Linux. Can you give me yoor dongle IP address? I will try making a GUI for connecting and disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running the install.sh by either double-clicking it in Nautilus then clicking 'Run in Terminal'. Or you could bring up the Terminal (search in dash for 'Terminal') then typing `./where it is stored/install.sh`. Then see what happens...

Comment: umm did this got the following error:
abhishek@Abhishek:~$ ./Documents/install.sh

..................start install.................

*** Check for root - failed

*** Please retry as root user.

press any key to exit....

Comment: Instead of typing just `./where it is stored/install.sh` please put `sudo ./where it is stored/install.sh`

Comment: The program requires root privelages. Make sure you got the files from a official or secure source.

Comment: yupp the files were provided in the dongle itself...what does root privelages mean exactly?

Comment: Root means every permission on your system. Root can literally do ANYTHING. look at the comment above 'The program...' and do that..

Comment: If the files are on the dongle they are safe.